# Extract Text and Images from a table in Word using "Spire.Doc for.Net" library

Tags: asp.net

Extract Images and text from word document using "Spire.Doc for.Net" library

My requirement is to retrieve text and images of a table cells from a word document and  save into a database, for that I am  using "Spire.Doc for.Net" library to retrieve text and images from word doc.

I am able to extract the images and text from a word file individually. But when i try to extract images and text from a table cells of a word doc together, i am getting text only not images from a table cells.

I and new to "Spire.Doc for.Net library", I tried to google but not able to find the right 
    solution, how to extract text and images from a table cells and save into database.

[image: **raw word Doc table data**]

Note: For reference I followed this link to extract image and text from word doc

- http://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.Doc/Spire.Doc-Program-Guide/NET-Extract-Image-Extract-Images-from-Word-in-C-and-VB.NET.html
- http://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.Doc/Spire.Doc-Program-Guide/Extract-Text-from-Word-in-C-and-VB.NET.html.

  Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Why did you tag this [tag:c]? Can you please explain?